# $\int_0^1\frac{1}{r}\frac{1}{\left[\log\left(1+\frac{1}{r}\right)\right]^n}dr$ finite?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

Does someone have a hint for me why the integral
$\int_0^1\frac{1}{r}\frac{1}{\left[\log\left(1+\frac{1}{r}\right)\right]^n}dr$
is finite? $n$ is a natural number greater than $1$.

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{1}{dr}$ or just $dr$

Comment: the only ''nasty'' point is $r=0$ what happens there?

Comment: Yes, with $dr$ in the denominator, it is clearly written incorrectly.  So maybe close it until JohnSmith corrects it.

Comment: Sorry for my typo - $dr$ in the denominator does not really make sense. I've corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

The only singularity is at $r=0$ It is enough to consider the integral on an interval $(0,a)$ with $0<a<1$. Near $r=0$ we have
$$
\log\Bigl(1+\frac1r\Bigr)=\log(1+r)-\log r\sim\log r,
$$
and
$$
\int_0^a\frac{dr}{r(\log r)^n}=\int_{-\infty}^{\log a}\frac{dt}{t^n}=\frac{1}{n-1}(\log a)^{1-n}.
$$